# Problem with Authorization with IIS and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, authorization

Got some problem with settings up the Authorization.
First i got :

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

So i deny all unknown users and then allow them to view those pages:

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Public">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Now to the problem .. they can access the Public pages and Default.aspx .. but not www.mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com/ .. so www.mydmain.com/Default.aspx works fine.
So how to make those work ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep in mind that there's a fundamental difference in protected resources between WebForms and MVC.  In WebForms, the resources you're trying to protect are the pages themselves, and since the pages exist on disk at a well-known path you can use Web.config to secure them.  However, in MVC, the resources you're trying to protect are actually controllers and actions, not individual paths and pages.  If you try protecting the path rather than the controller, your application likely has a security vulnerability.

In MVC, by default all controllers + actions are accessible to all users, both authenticated and guest.  To secure controllers or actions, the [Authorize] attribute has been provided.  See http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/#MVC_Security for more information.

In short, it sounds like for your application you'd want to attribute every controller *except* the default controller and the Public controller with the [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: Thanks alot .. that seems like a smart solution :)

Comment: The update MVC 4 version of this can be found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx