# Excluding an action from authorization in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I am using forms authentication in my ASP.NET MVC application. I want to the signup page from the authorization process. I know I can add a location tag in my main web.config file or create a new web.config inside the specific folder. But I just to exclude one specific action in the User controller. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

**Do not use Web.config <location> authorization in an MVC application.**  Doing so will lead to security vulnerabilities in your web site.

Instead, use the [Authorize] attribute to control who has access to certain controllers or actions.  (You can use the [Authorize] attribute on a controller's type if you want it to apply to all actions in that controller.)

More information:

- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

Comment: Isn't there a "good" way to manage these authorization rules other than compiling them into website?  I'd love to be able to tweak the rules without having to redeploy the app.

Comment: see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx for the MVC 4 version of Levi's comments

Answer (score 2):

[Try this slick way to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684150/is-this-slick-way-to-exclude-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc)

It adds the ability to exclude Controller-level filters from an action.

```
[ExcludeFilter(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute)]  
public ActionMethod DontAuthorize.....
```

Much easier!

Answer (score 1):

You could also have created your own AllowWithoutAuthorisation attribute and decorated that ActionResult with it.

**EDIT**
This is kinda untested but couldn't you do;

```
[Authorize(Users="*")]
```

**EDIT 2**

Or you could decorate each ActionResult with [Authorise] and ommit the one you want not to have authorised.

Comment: None of these work since the Authorize attribute on the controller runs even after the Action runs.

Comment: I used `[AllowAnonymous]`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have got it.

What I did is, I created a separate controller for that action and added a location element in my web.config to allow anonymous access to that action.

This will allow all access to that controller without authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to the method (as recommended by Jeremy) worked for me as well.