# Can IIS Request Limits <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="x"> be applied to specific ASP.NET Routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, web-config, asp.net-routing

I'm looking at the IIS 7 [Request Limits `<requestLimits>`](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits) setting, specifically `maxAllowedContentLength` and was wondering if this could be applied at the [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) level?  I am working in an ASP.NET MVC 3 project that allows for file uploads, but I want to only allow the larger requests for those specific routes.

This question is similar to the unanswered [Can I increase maxRequestLength of ASP.NET request for MVC Controller Action with additional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049263/can-i-increase-maxrequestlength-of-asp-net-request-for-mvc-controller-action-wit)

An answer to [Where do I catch and handle maxAllowedContentLength exceeded in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567273/where-do-i-catch-and-handle-maxallowedcontentlength-exceeded-in-iis7) seems to imply I can do something like this, but I was looking for confirmation or other ideas.

```
protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
{
    Exception err = Server.GetLastError();
    if (err is HttpException)
    {
        if ((err as HttpException).WebEventCode == 3004)
        {
            // check to see if upload request and let through
            Server.Transfer( Context.Request.Url.LocalPath );
            return;
        }
    }
    base.OnError(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the `<requestLimits>` element in a `<location>` tag for the (fake) virtual directory corresponding to that route.

I don't know of any better solution.